# Deal with huge dataset?

Tags: raster, maxlength, large-data

I need to plot a countrywide raster. I tried cellsize=300 and use 64-bit system. Memory.limit() is 8148. When running the code, it still gives me an "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.6 Gb". Sometimes, Windows stops working--even worse...

Is there any other way that I can deal with such large dataset? Btw, I am more familiar with ArcGIS. Thanks!!!

{

```
    x.min <- -6328997.74765339; x.max <- 2182662.25234661 # Extent of easting coordinates
    y.min <- 310413.438361092; y.max <- 5448183.43836109 # Extent of northing coordinates
    n <- 2351      
    center <- read.csv ("J:\\...,header=T)
    attach(center)
    center <- as.matrix (center) # XY corrdinates #    
    emp <- read.csv ("J:\\...,header=T, sep=",")
    attach(emp)

    n.rows <- 17126
    cellsize <- 300
    n.cols <- 28373

    x.max <- x.min + n.cols * cellsize          # Assures square cells are used#
    y.0 <- seq(y.max-cellsize/2, y.min+cellsize/2, length.out=n.rows) 
    x.0 <- seq(x.min+cellsize/2, x.max-cellsize/2, length.out=n.cols)   

system.time(
  {
    i <- order(emp, decreasing=TRUE)
    emp <- emp[i]
    center <- center[i, , drop=FALSE]

    owner <- matrix(0, n.rows, n.cols)
    gravity.max <- matrix(0, n.rows, n.cols)

    for (i in 1:n) {
      r <- emp[i] / outer((y.0 - center[i,2])^2, (x.0 - center[i,1])^2, "+")
      update <- which(r >= gravity.max)
      gravity.max[update] <- r[update]
      owner[update] <- i
    }  
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try the [raster package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/index.html).

raster can work with large rasters. It is used by lots of people who do spatial analyses in R.

You will save a lot of time if you first read the vignette [Introduction to the raster package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/Raster.pdf) to get familiar with the package.